# Error Call to a member function getDescription()

Tags: magento-1.9, fatal-error

Getting these errors below the footer of the `category pages`.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function
>   getDescription() on null in
>   /var/www/html/app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/template/page/2columns-left.phtml:77
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241):
>   include() #1
>   /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/ultimo...') #2
>   /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView() #3
>   /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml() #4
>   /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(556):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml() #5
>   /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput() #6
>   /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php(161):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout() #7
>   /var/www/html/app/code/community/Vinagento/Vpager/controllers/CategoryController.php(30):
>   Mage_Cat in
>   /var/www/html/app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/template/page/2columns-left.phtml
>   on line 77

Please help me to solve this..

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Answer (score 1):

The 'object' from where you are calling getDescription() is not created, if 'object' is your collection then might be 'description' is not its attribute and if an 'object' is your block then this block has no getDescription() function defined.